# Is it possible to GROUP BY multiple columns using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Is it possible to `GROUP BY` more than one column in a MySQL `SELECT` query? For example:

```
GROUP BY fV.tier_id AND 'f.form_template_id'
```

Comment: You can't group by rows. You can group by columns though

Comment: You may need to do a subquery instead of using multiple group by clauses.

Comment: While most of the high-voted answers are essentially the same as each other (they show the correct syntax, and explain the effect of switching the order of the two columns), if your need is somewhat different, consider [Daniklad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42159638/199364).

Answer (score 384):

```
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

Answer (score 194):

Yes, you can group by multiple columns. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

The results will first be grouped by col1, then by col2. In MySQL, column preference goes from left to right.

Comment: Preference of left to right is applied to the ascending order of the groupings and not the column group preference. `GROUP BY` applies `col1+col2`. e.g. `col1 = 1, 2, 1, 2 | col2 = 1, 2, 3, 2` and running `GROUP BY col1,col2` would return `1,1|1,3|2,2` as opposed to `1,1|2,2` as suggested. Whereas `GROUP BY col2, col1` would change the ascending order of col2 returning. `1,1|2,2|1,3`  Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5f69/1 Note that row id: 2 is returned in both cases for `2,2` despite inverting the columns.

Comment: One more testing. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c8763/2 Conclusion. At first mysql sorts by the first defined column (with `GROUP BY`). And if in the first defined column there are equal results, then only within the equal results sorts by the second defined column

Comment: Regarding `SUM` using with `GROUP BY`. If `GROUP BY` only by one column, then `SUM`s all values of each distinct (different) the column value http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cbde2/2. If `GROUP BY` two columns. Then mysql at first checks if for the first column value there are different values in the second column. If yes, then mysql `SUM` each different value of the second column http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cbde2/1.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, but what does grouping by more two columns mean? Well, it's the same as grouping by each unique pair per row. The order you list the columns changes the way the rows are sorted.

In your example, you would write

`GROUP BY fV.tier_id, f.form_template_id`

Meanwhile, the code

`GROUP BY f.form_template_id, fV.tier_id`

would give similar results, but sorted differently.

Answer (score 22):

If you prefer (I need to apply this) group by two columns at same time, I just saw this point:

```
SELECT CONCAT (col1, '_', col2) AS Group1 ... GROUP BY Group1
```

Comment: See ypercube's comments under lada's answer. Consider as an alternative: `SELECT CONCAT(col1, '_', col2) FROM GROUP BY col1, col2`. The results will usually *look* the same as this answer, but the internal execution is quite different.

Answer (score 21):

```
group by fV.tier_id, f.form_template_id
```

Answer (score 20):

To use a simple example, I had a counter that needed to summarise unique IP addresses per visited page on a site. Which is basically grouping by pagename and then by IP. I solved it with a combination of DISTINCT and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT pagename, COUNT(DISTINCT ipaddress) AS visit_count FROM log_visitors GROUP BY pagename ORDER BY visit_count DESC;
```

Comment: This answer is worth noting, as it solves a somewhat different problem than the other answers.

Answer (score -8):

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(col1, '_', col2)
```

Comment: I wonder how an answer with just one line of code, posted 4 years after the question had been answered gets 8 (eight!) upvotes. While also being incorrect and inefficient besides late and short.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ why do you say it's incorrect? This is exactly what I was looking for, and a correct interpretation of "group by multiple columns". In fact, I don't know why this isn't the behavior of "group by col1, col2" like I'd expect

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue I don't what you have been looking for exactly but `GROUP BY CONCAT(col1, '_', col2)` has many downsides compared to ``GROUP BY col1, col2`.

Comment: @Abram pinging you, so you see my reply to NeverEndingQueue. Downsides: it's less - much less -- efficient than `GROUP BY col1, col2`. It will give wrong results with some data. Say `col1, col2` have values: `('a_b', 'c')` in one row and `('a', 'b_c')` in another. This wrong answer, with GROUP BY CONCAT will aggregate the two rows in one. The correct answer will not.

Comment: No one stops you from using the CONCAT expression in the SELECT list by the way, if you need it: `SELECT CONCAT(col1, '_', col2) ... FROM ... GROUP BY col1, col2 ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ oops, stupidly I was thinking "group by foo, bar" behaved like "... group by foo union ... group by bar". It would be an unusual case indeed to GROUP BY CONCAT.