# Confusion in Group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table similar to:

```
user_id     |   action

 1                a1                  
 2                a1
 1                a1
 3                a1
 2                a1
 1                a2
 2                a2
```

I have to find out the number of users who have done action a1, group by number of actions and number of users for a1.

eg in the above table, the output should be:

```
num_users          num_action_a1
1 (user: 3)             1
2  (user: 1,2)          2
```

I tried following query

```
select user_id, count(user_id) from table where action = 'a1' group by user_id
```

Do I have to use nested group by ?

Comment: What query did you try?

Comment: select user_id, count(user_id) from table where action = 'a1' group by user_id - I'm confused about using 2 group by

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841426/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-columns-using-mysql

Comment: Again tried: select user_id, count(user_id) from table where query_type = 'a1' group by user_id, count(user_id) - Didn't work :(

Comment: Try this SELECT count(user_id) num_users FROM table WHERE action=a1 GROUP BY (SELECT count(user_id) no_users FROM  table ASC),(SELECT count(user_id) FROM table WHERE action=a1)

Comment: I'm getting this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC),(SELECT count(user_id) FROM action_table WHERE query_type = 'a1')' at line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56923/discussion-between-guna-seelan-and-saurabh-verma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sub query to get the counts per user id, then selecting from that the users and counts:-

```
SELECT num_users, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS actual_users , COUNT(*) AS num_action_a1
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS num_users
    FROM some_table
    WHERE action = 'a1'
    GROUP BY user_id
) sub0
GROUP BY num_users
```

Comment: Getting this error:
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Just needs an alias name for the sub query (I have just added it as sub0)