# Group by two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    items.*
FROM
    `items` 
INNER JOIN
    `users` ON `items`.`owner` = `users`.`id` 
GROUP BY
    `items`.`owner` 
LIMIT
    10
```

I ensures it is grouped by the user (only one item fetched per user), but I also wish ensure that items with the category, say, "1" only appears once.

But that does not work. Well, query succeeds, but it does not group by category. Multiple categories is still shown. Any ideas?

I have created a SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4bad/1

Instead of outputting:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID | CATEGORY | OWNER |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        1 |     1 |
|  2 |        1 |     2 |
|  3 |        1 |     3 |
|  4 |        2 |     4 |
|  5 |        2 |     5 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

It should be outputting:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID | CATEGORY | OWNER |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        1 |     1 |
|  4 |        2 |     2 |
|  5 |        2 |     4 |
|  5 |        2 |     5 |
|  8 |        3 |     3 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

(notice category 1 is only shown ONCE).

I want to ensure that only one item per owner is shown, and then adtionally ensure that a specific category (say 1 and 5) is only shown once. The category 1 and 5 are overpopulated, and if they are not limited, they will be 90% of the output.

Comment: It looks fine to me.  When you say "it doesnt work" what does that mean? Do you get an error, if so what is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to GROUP BY multiple columns using MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841426/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-columns-using-mysql)

Comment: It doesn't look fine to me.  Selecting * with a group by clause never looks fine to me.  Neither does a limit clause without an order by clause.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Strawberry, my point was to get OP to post their error (it looks fine to me syntactically, not logically).  Dan's point was that its not standard sql and ought to be re-thought.  Both valid IMO.

Comment: I see, what I initally wrote was confusing. I have updated my question, alongside with a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4bad/1

Comment: Now, i'm a bit more confused.  You want to see unique owners, but also want to see unique categories.  Which owners do you want to *not* show?

Comment: The fiddle is great, but perhaps you can add to your question what your expected output should be?

Comment: @paqogomez this is now done, thanks.

Comment: I want to ensure that only one item per owner is shown, and then adtionally ensure that a specific category (say 1 and 5) is only shown once. The category 1 and 5 are overpopulated, and if they are not limited, they will be 90% of the output.

Comment: Lets take this [conversation to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67150/group-by-two-values)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67152/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-mattias).

Comment: Where does 4,2,2 come from? And each category appears to be exactly as populous as any other. Frankly, I have no idea what's going on here. Other than that, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT to retrieve unique data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.category
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from items t1
where category not in (1,2)
or not exists (
    select 1 from items t2
    where t2.id < t1.id
    and t2.category = t1.category
)
group by owner
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4bad/27

Comment: Thanks for the try, but the two issues: 1. Not all results are being shown (see for instance: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4bad/22) 2. In the real query, I need to order by a specific `distance` field (currently you are ordering by category).

Comment: @Mattias see update, although I don't this query will not guarantee the results you want because mysql randomly selects a category since you're only grouping by owner