# Grouping by multiple columns with equal priority in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data, and I want to be able to output all the data that does not repeat the contents of two columns, an illustration:

**Example table:**

```
Column1 | Column2  | Column3
   1         XX        pop
   2         YY        yif
   3         ZZ        pop
   4         PP        pop
   5         XX        pop
   6         YY        yif
   7         PP        Hor
   8         MM        tre
   9         PP        pop
  10         XX        pop   
  11         MM        pop
```

What I want to do here is output all rows where the values for **both** Columns 2 and 3 are not repeated, so you will see that `Column1` == 1 and `Column1` == 5 have the same values in both `Column2` and `Column3`, so they only need to output where `Column1` == 1 and not =5 (or =10).

I would like to set the query to output all rows, except where `Column1` == 5,6,9,10 because these have both `Column2` *and* `Column3` repetition.

**Intended output of query: *(note: all three columns are required)***

```
Column1 | Column2  | Column3
   1         XX        pop
   2         YY        yif
   3         ZZ        pop
   4         PP        pop
   7         PP        Hor
   8         MM        tre 
  11         MM        pop
```

I have tried looking into Group By but this only appears to group by one column, or at least groups them from left to right so `GROUP BY (Column2, Column3)` would `GROUP BY` all values in `Column2` *and then* values in `Column3` rather than treat both columns equally.

I found one possible solution which was to concat the columns beforehand, such as

```
GROUP BY CONCAT(Column2, '_', Column3)
```

From  [Is it possible to GROUP BY multiple columns using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841426/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-columns-using-mysql)  but this has been vaguely criticised  (at least, as an answer to that question), but seems the closest code I've seen to do what I want to do.

- **So, how *should* I structure my `GROUP BY` clause to reach this outcome?**
- Is the `GROUP BY CONCAT` I have found a good way of approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` on multiple columns is possible. Depending on the result you want, you have to apply extra `GROUP` functions to the rest of your data. In your case it looks like you want the first **column1** index, and unique combinations of **(column2,column3)**

The following query should do the trick:

```
SELECT MIN(column1) AS column1,column2,column3
FROM table1
GROUP BY column2,column3
ORDER BY MIN(column1) ASC;
```

Comment: Testing this SQL code, this appears to return what I'm looking for, thanks. Can you explain a little about how the `SELECT MIN(column1) AS column1,column2,column3 ` influences the `GROUP BY`, I don't really recognise that syntax . Thanks

Comment: I think the select Min just gives the lowest ID for that combination of column 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about Column1 at all, you don't even need `GROUP BY`. Just use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column2, Column3
FROM the_table
ORDER BY however_you_want
;
```

Otherwise, Norbert's answer is probably more fitting.

Comment: thanks, but of all the columns, Column1 was the most required!