# Creating a SQL view from tables without UIDs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables:

- match_rating, which have data on a team's performance in a match. There are naturally two tuples for every matchId (since there are two teams to each match). The PK is matchId, teamId.
- event, which has information on events during matches. The PK is an autoincremented UID, and it contains the Foreign Keys match_id and subject_team_id as well.

Now I want to create a new view which counts how many times certain events happen in a match, for each team, with fields like this:

[image: DB table fields]

But for the life of me I cannot get around the fact that there are 1) two tuples for each match in the match_rating table, and 2) querying the event table on match_id returns events for both teams.

The closest I got was something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN evt.event_type_id = 101 THEN 1
            WHEN evt.event_type_id = 111 THEN 1
            WHEN evt.event_type_id = 121 THEN 1
            [etc]
        END    
    ) AS 'mid_chances',
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN evt.event_type_id = 103 THEN 1
            WHEN evt.event_type_id = 113 THEN 1
            WHEN evt.event_type_id = 123 THEN 1
            [etc]
        END    
    ) AS 'right_chances',
    mr.tactic,
    mr.tactic_skill,
    mr.bp,
    evt.match_id,
    evt.subject_team_id    
FROM event evt
JOIN match_rating mr
     ON evt.match_id = mr.match_id
WHERE   evt.event_type_id BETWEEN 100 AND 104 OR 
        evt.event_type_id BETWEEN 110 AND 114 OR 
        evt.event_type_id BETWEEN 120 AND 124 OR 
        [etc]
GROUP BY evt.match_id  
ORDER BY `right_chances`  DESC
```

But still, this counts the events twice, reporting 2 events where there was only 1, 6 for 3 events and so on. I have tried grouping on team_id as well (GROUP BY evt.match_id AND team_id) , but that returns only 2 rows with all events counted.

I hope I have made my problem clear, and it should be obvious that I really need a good tip or two.

Edit for clarity (sorry):
Sample data for match_rating table:
[image]

Sample data for the event table:
[image]

What I would like to see as the result is this:
[image]

That is, two tuples for each match, one for each team, where the types of events that team had is summed up. Thanks so much for looking into this!

Comment: Please edit your post to include example fields and data from the two tables, and expected final output based on that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update after comments/feedback**

OK.. just to confirm, what you want is

- Each row of the output represents a team within a match
- Other values (other than match_id and team_id) are sums or other aggregations across multiple rows?

If that is the case, then I believe you should be doing a GROUP BY the match_id and team_id. This should cause the correct number of rows to be generated (one for each match_id/team_id combination). You say in your question that you have tried it already - I suggest reviewing it (potentially after also considering the below).

With your data, it appears that the 'event' table also has a field which indicates the team_id. To ensure you only get the relevant team's events, I suggest your join between match_rating and event be on both fields e.g.,

```
FROM event evt
JOIN match_rating mr
     ON evt.match_id = mr.match_id
     AND evt.subject_team_id = mr.team_id
```

---

**Previous answer - does not answer the question (as per later comments)**

Just confirming - the issue is that when you run it, for each match it returns 2 rows - one for each team - but you want to do processing on both teams as one row only?

As such, you could do a few things (e.g., self-join the match rating table to itself, with Team1 ratings and Team2 ratings).

Alternatively, you could modify your FROM to have joins to match_rating twice - where the first has the lower ID for the two teams e.g.,

```
FROM event evt
JOIN match_rating mr_team1
     ON evt.match_id = mr_team1.match_id
JOIN match_rating mr_team2
     ON evt.match_id = mr_team2.match_id
     AND mr_team1.match_id < mr_team2.match_id
```

Of course, your processing then needs to be modified to take this into account e.g., one row represents a match, and you have a bunch of data for team1 and similar data for team2. You'd then, I assume, compare the data for team1 columns and team2 columns to get some sort of rating etc (e.g., chance for Team1 to win, etc).

Comment: It's not quite what I'm aiming for - please look at my update to the question.
I'm sorry for being unclear and thanks a bunch for your time :)

Comment: Thanks for your time seanb, I really appreciate this - and yes, that's what I'm looking for.
I did as you suggested, but I still only get those two rows. I made a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/LOhSS7M.
Yes, some events have no subject_team_id, since not all events involve a specific team - but I don't think that should matter...?

Comment: If there are some events that don't have match_ratings for both teams, you can use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN to still report on all pairs e.g., `FROM event evt
LEFT JOIN match_rating mr ON ...` Regarding the group-by: I don't code MySQL specifically, but I think your GROUP BY has issues. Instead of `GROUP BY evt.match_id AND evt.subject_team_id`, try using commas between fields e.g., `GROUP BY evt.match_id, evt.subject_team_id` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841426/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-columns-using-mysql

Comment: You may also need to review your fields after you get the GROUP BY working. Every field should either be a) part of the group-by, or b) be some sort of aggregate (sum, max, avg, etc). For example, you have two fields in the SELECT component  `mr.tactic_type` and `mr.tactic_skill` that don't have this specified. It's not clear what you want to happen with them.

Comment: Finally, you may also want to review your SQL mode, particularly for ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93b3f703b09667d5ce79a1fd0ce9f32c) showing a relatively simple scenario and multiple attempts at grouping - seeing what works and what doesn't. The first result (labelled 'standard SQL') is a template of what we *should* be getting.