# How to do grouping by multiple columns in MySQL Select Statement

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, groupwise-maximum

[image]

Above is the output from my Select Statement in MySQL, can anyone please help me so that I can group above result by exp_date and username. So **it will be only 1 row for any username for the same date**.

It should show lodging, boarding, laundry, and conveyance column's value in a single row of 2021-10-26 for username S.M.gadekar.

Tried all the ideas but I am not getting the exact result. What is the actual optimized solution for this?

Comment: `GROUP BY username, exp_date`

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html for the functions you can use to aggregate the other columns in each group.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to GROUP BY multiple columns using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841426/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-columns-using-mysql)

Comment: If you can use `MAX()` or `SUM()`, see Andrew's answer, else see the `[groupwise-maximum]` tag.

Comment: @RickJames you can link tags in comments with `[tag:]` syntax like [tag:groupwise-maximum]

Answer (score 1):

You select the columns you want out of your group, and use some kind of aggregate and alias for the rest - since it looks like all expense values for one date and name are set in only one row, `MAX()` could work, but `SUM()` is the safer choice for aggregation here. To group by multiple columns, just have a comma separated list of columns in your `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT username, exp_date, 
    SUM(lodging) AS lodging,
    SUM(boarding) AS boarding,
    SUM(laundry) AS laundry,
    SUM(conveyance) AS conveyance
FROM table
GROUP BY exp_date, username;
```

That said the table should probably be normalized into three tables, since this looks like it's only in 2nd normal form - but the design works well enough for the purpose.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/195c05/2)

If you specifically want a row for one person on one day, not a row for each person each day there is data, your where clause goes between your from and group clauses:

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/195c05/3)

Answer (score 0):

- more than column group by separated by ,
  **GROUP BY exp_date , username;**