# Counting value for third column using two existing columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Say, in mysql, I have a column doctor and a column patient. One doctor can have multiple patients and one patient can have multiple doctors. Here is an example table:

| Doctor | Patient |
| --- | --- |
| Carson | Alisson |
| Carson | Alisson |
| Carson | Alisson |
| Carson | Becker |
| Carson | Becker |
| Daniel | Alisson |
| Daniel | Alisson |
| Daniel | David |

I would like the code to produce a table which shows the doctor, his patient and how many times the patient appeared with this doctor. This is what it would look like:

| Doctor | Patient | Count(Patient) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carson | Alisson | 3 |
| Carson | Becker | 2 |
| Daniel | Alisson | 2 |
| Daniel | David | 1 |

So far, and because I am new to mysql, my code has produced a table that looks like this:

| Doctor | Patient | Count(Patient) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carson | Alisson | 5 |
| Carson | Becker | 2 |
| Daniel | David | 1 |

As you can see, my code assigns a patient to one doctor. In this case, Alisson is assigned to Carson even though Alisson is a patient of Daniel as well.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
    select doctor, patient, count(*) from information
    group by patient
```

I assume that I get the wrong table because I am grouping by patient. However, in order to receive the desired table, I would need to group by both patient and doctor, which I do not know how to do. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Umesh

Comment: Did you try searching for any help on your own? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841426/is-it-possible-to-group-by-multiple-columns-using-mysql) took me 30 seconds to find.

Comment: I did not know until after I had written my question. The moment I posted it, I found this link after googling 'how to do group by with 2 columns': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns. I can delete this thread or keep it here. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just group by both

```
select doctor, patient, count(*)
from information
group by doctor, patient
```

Comment: @UmeshShreeman -- you are welcome -- on this website if a question helps you up vote it.  If it answers your question you click on the check mark.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and clicked the check mark! Edit: Apparently, I need 15 reputation to cast a vote but I have clicked on it anyway(website says feedback will be recorded), in case the upvote does not show up.